# setting focus on shown input field

Tags: jquery, input, focus, show

I am trying to set focus to the input text field with id="message-add" when it is showed using jQuery. I think i should use 'live()' or 'delegate' and the function focus() to get it to work? Which should be used and how should it be written?

```
$("#message-add").show();
$("#message-add").focus();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, if the `input` is hidden, which is what I think the Q is stating?

```
<button>Show</button>
<input id="message-add" />

$('#message-add').hide();

$('button').click(function(){
    $('#message-add').show().focus();    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/FhB8u/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#message-add").focus; // Add Parens .focus()
```

This option should work just fine, but you need to add the parens after the method call.

You may need to do this if you want it on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#message-add").focus();
});
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/TnHyN/